# Why did those German Dancers chase after the Griswolds?

Tags: plot-explanation, european-vacation

In [*National Lampoon's European Vacation* (1985)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Lampoon%27s_European_Vacation), when there's a fight with the German dancers Clark dances with and the Griswolds run away and drive away as fast as they can, why do those German dancers chase after them with ropes? What were they going to do to them?

Answer (score 1):

When the dancing starts out, Clark is simply being awkward and clumsy, but as it progresses, he gets more agitated and aggressive, especially after getting slapped. He eventually delivers a punch to his perceived antagonist and is promptly punched off the stage himself. This creates the brawl amongst the revelers.

Immediately after this scene, they cut back to Rusty and the fraulein, Claudia, whom he's making out with. She abruptly stops.

> Claudia:Those bells have not rung in years.
>   Rusty: what does that mean?
>   Claudia: It means they are going to hang someone.
>   Rusty: DAD!

So the Oktoberfest crowd was preparing to murder Clark Griswold via hanging.